# How do Google Analytics collect "user language" data?

Tags: google-analytics

Do GA collect via `window.navigator.language` on js side or use a `Accept-Language` header check on server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Analytics reads language preference from the `Accept-Language` header.  See more about this here http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/02/12/languages-report-google-analytics/ and here https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12942/does-google-analytics-track-users-with-multiple-languages

Comment: That Lunametrics link is _exceptionally_ useful; I've just relied on it quite heavily to answer a client request. Thank you.

Comment: There are a few inaccuracies in the lunametrics page. (1) A language tag with the script included (`sr-Latn-RS`) is not misformatted. It complies with BCP47 (section 2.2.3): some languages can be written in different scripts, and then specifying which one is preferred makes sense. (2) In `es-419`, `419` is not a country code, but it is still an allowed value for BCP47 (section 2.2.3): 419 is the UN M.49 (three-digit) code for Latin Amerca and the Caribbean.