# How does Google Analytics pull the browser 'language' of the visitor? Does this differ from OS>OS and browser>browser?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

We recently implemented a js redirect based on the language returned with'navigator.language' and 'navigator.BrowserLanguage'.
Before deciding to move forward with the redirect, I did a quick review of what navigator.language (navigator.BrowserLanguage for IE) returned on various browsers and operating systems.
Here is what I found:
[navigator.language table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOQM5.png)

As you can see, the results were not very consistent. There are a number of SO articles that hinted at similar outcomes.

I decided it was best to use 'navigator.language' and not 'navigator.lanuages' because it seemed to return the most consistent results. I can provide details for expected behavior for each of the scenarios in my screenshot linked above.

My Question: How is Google Analytics pulling browser language? If it is using the results returned from 'navigator.language', I would argue that accurately targeting the desired language would be easier across browsers and various operating systems. If they are using the first position returned in the array from navigator.languages, results will likely be less accurate.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Looks like this has been flagged as a duplicate. I think the [Lunametrics](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/02/12/languages-report-google-analytics/) article is super thorough, but they do not go into the many exceptions made for different browsers/operating systems. Now that we have determined the the request header params are what GA reports on, I guess I would be interested in learning how they deal with the inconsistent browser/os behavior.

Comment: I think it's taken from the request header `Accept-Language`

Comment: thanks @ChrisSatchell. If we need to use js for this redirect, it may make more sense to take a look at navigator.languages then, so we can grab the most preferred language. It looks like the accept-language parameter is set using the browser settings, and returns all acceptable languages (Example from my Chrome: Accept-Language:de-DE,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,de;q=0.4).How does GA determine which accept-language value to report on if there are multiple? This article on content negation starts to get into it. I'm not sure how GA handles. developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do Google Analytics collect "user language" data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838214/how-do-google-analytics-collect-user-language-data)

Comment: Thanks, I think that Lunametrics article is pretty helpful but could be more thorough. "Google Analytics simply reports the first preference in the browser." On a PC, chrome lang settings allow you to select a preferred language without re-ordering. So the request header returns Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,de-AT;q=0.6,de;q=0.4, but I have told Chrome I want my browser to display in de-AT. In this specific case, it sounds like GA would bucket me under en-US, when it reality I should fall under de-AT